# Installed phantomjs with npm but showing no installation path

Tags: node.js, macos, npm-install

I installed npm with home brew in my mac. After this, I tried installing phantomJS with the command `npm install phantom phantomjs -g`. After the installation, the command `which phantomJS` is showing `phantomjs not found`. How can I solve this problem ? I am using macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
npm install phantom --save

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the phantomJS executable to your `PATH`,

To add it to your PATH, symbolically link phantomJS it into /usr/local/bin:

> sudo ln -s /path/to/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/